# Bibtex and Tableofcontents appear under specific conditions?

Tags: biblatex, table-of-contents, luatex

I'm trying to build a pdf with latex.
My LaTeX file does build correctly with the LaTeX Workshop extension in VSCode.

But when I am trying to build my document using a makefile with this command :

```
all:  ## Compile paper
    lualatex document.tex
    rm *.toc
    rm *.aux
    rm *.out
    rm *.log
```

The pdf builds correctly (without errors) but without my tableofcontent and my references.
The solution I found for uncertain reasons is to duplicate my LaTeX command :

```
all:  ## Compile paper
    lualatex document.tex
    lualatex document.tex
    rm *.toc
    rm *.aux
    rm *.out
    rm *.log
```

This generates correctly the table of content but not the references using biblatex.
Do you have a solution ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The solution for references is correct. As for bibliography: you are not running bibtex/biber.

Comment: What is the command I need thought ? I order to compile all in one command or one set of commands ?

Comment: That depends on which backend you use with biblatex. Either it's biber or bibtex. And make sure to have at least one lualatex run before calling that and at least one afterwards.

Comment: Btw, I don't know VS Code's LaTeX Workshop but it probably uses latexmk. So if you are fine with guesswork of what is needed to compile your document, you might as well use that directly.

Comment: I am quite a beginner with LaTeX but I'm gonna try things and I'll comeback